# looking for IP address in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ip

I just handed over a project which technical responsible person quit.
My client asked me to fix problem on their service they just know which domain but none of server ip and how to access.
Since they uses aws I looked for ip address which digged from domain but can't find in Ec2, load balancer and elastic ip.
By IP search, this ip address is served by amazon aws.

How can I find this server from ip address.

- I can access to my customer's aws account.
- I can access dns of customer's service domain.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your situation is:

- You have a **domain name** that points to an **IP address**
- You wish to **find the EC2 instance(s)** that the IP address points to

An IP address could be associated with:

- An EC2 instance IP address
- An Elastic IP address, which is then associated with an EC2 instance
- *Not* a load balancer (it uses a DNS Name, not an IP address -- except for the new Network Load Balancer, but it is unlikely they are using this)
- An database instance (eg RDS, Redshift, Elasticache) but this is unlikely as you are saying that the IP address is responding with web traffic

Therefore, the best thing to do would be to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to list all IP addresses on EC2 instances and Elastic IPs:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,PublicIpAddress] --output text

aws ec2 describe-addresses --query Addresses[*].[NetworkInterfaceId,PrivateIpAddress] --output text
```

Run the above commands **in every Region** and you should find where that particular IP address is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to the billing section of the AWS Account and verify there are EC2 instances running under the AWS account provided to you.

**Username in menu bar (top right corner) -> My Billing Dashboard -> Bills -> Details -> Elastic Compute Cloud -> Region of your EC2 instances**

If you find instances in a particular region by switching to it and then you should be able to find the EC2 instance and SSH/RDP to it using the Key.pem file given to you(Or need to request it from your customer)